# How to make test case for angular animations

Tags: angular, animation, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-animations

I use karma to write angular2 test cases, but have no idea how to test animations. I tried to get and check the transform attributes of host element, but got 'none', neither the 'getCalculateStyle()' method can work.
Any suggestions?

Example code to test:

```
func2Test() {
    const animations: AnimationMetadata[] = [animate('500ms ease-in', style({transform: `translate3d(100px, 0px, 0px)`}))];
    const myAnimation: AnimationFactory = this.animationBuilder.build(animations);
    const player = myAnimation.create(this.slickTrack.nativeElement);
    player.play();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i find an example

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/animations/browser/test/dsl/animation_spec.ts

```
it('should fill in missing starting steps when a starting `style()` value is not used',
           () => {
             const steps = [animate(1000, style({width: 999}))];

             const players = invokeAnimationSequence(rootElement, steps);
             expect(players[0].keyframes).toEqual([
               {width: AUTO_STYLE, offset: 0}, {width: 999, offset: 1}
             ]);
           });
```